# adding font to highcharts editor

Tags: javascript, highcharts, fonts, highcharts-editor

I've just downloaded the highcharts wysiwyg editor: 
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-editor/releases

I need an easy to use tool for my co-workers, who are artistically and graphically sophisticated but technically not up to monkeying with code.

I'd like to add a font to the editor, but I don't see how to do that. The documentation is cryptic. It says:

Fonts can be added to the available font set by:

```
highed.meta.fonts.push('Verdana');
```

But where I supposed to write this code? The editor seems to be a standalone thing without a way to customize code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is there any errors? - plunker example perhaps?

Comment: @Denis Tsoi: When you download the editor, there does not appear to be a way to edit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LauraNMS Had a quick look at the documentation:

Firstly, if you've cloned the repository, you will need to

*1.* go through the install, i.e.

```
npm install
gulp
```

*2.* go to your `dist/` folder.
 *3.* in your `standalone.html` add your desired font.
 *4.* add in font 
 *5.* before your script at the bottom, add in the following `highed.meta.fonts.push(FONTNAME);` *(Fontname is your usual font name like in CSS).*
 *6.* Go to your `stanealone.html` and into `Customise tab`.
 *7.* go to `Appearance` and click the `arrow down` after the font. *(this changes font)*

I've attached screenshots below to follow as well

In step 3 I used a Google Font

[image: Step 3]

Step 6:

[image: Step 6]

Comment: I don't see a dist folder. What's the link you're downloading from, please?

Comment: I see it now! Thank you, @Denis Tsoi!