# Using custom fonts with Highcharts

Tags: css, highcharts, typography

I am trying to apply 3rd party typography fonts to Highcharts line graphs,
like to X/Y axis labels, X axis titles, tooltips regular and bold, plotlines labels, etc.
I think, it should be done via CSS classes, like use class="abc-body-small" or "abc-body-small-heavier" (instead of b tag ) for a font/style, probably inside TS file which defines chartOptions.

Could someone please show how to do it?
(using Highcharts6 with Angular6)

TIA,
Oleg

Comment: Adding this font family for the whole chart in a `chart.style` config doesn't work in your case? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With fonts, you can append the css-styles as is shown in this fragment of code:

Example:

```
var newStyle = document.createElement('style');

newStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\
@font-face {\
  font-family: 'Pacifico';\
  font-style: normal;\
  font-weight: 400;\
  src: local('Pacifico Regular'), local('Pacifico-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pacifico/v13/FwZY7-Qmy14u9lezJ-6H6Mk.woff2) format('woff2');\
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;\
}\
"));

document.head.appendChild(newStyle);
```

Check these sources for more information:

1. [Custom fonts not working - Highcharts official support forum](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=42200)
2. [Jsfiddle used in the source # 1](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hypobxq0)
3. [highcharts js custom font - Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=hightcharts%20js%20custom%20font&rlz=1C1GCEA_enCO941CO941&oq=hightcharts%20js%20custom%20font%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i10i160l3.6800j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
4. [Answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42800152/12511801)

Comment: Marco, do I really have to define new styles in that case or can just point to the 3rd party font as:  this.chartOptions.xAxis.title: { style: {
      fontFamily: "abc-body-small"  //"highcharts-axis-title"
    } }     I mean, those 3rd party fonts are fully defined including size, weight, etc.   Do I really have to wrap all that in new CSS style to use them?

Comment: @user1981152 I can't say for sure (*the sources I've added in my answer were based on google search - not actual code*), but those results seems to work (*especially the jsfiddle found at point # 2*), I should try and use whatever works.

Comment: In my app I use those fonts with  div's just by putting   class="abc-body-small".  There should be something similar in Highcharts, maybe class or classname. I tried to use that style.fontFamily, it seem to change something visually a bit, however if you inspect it, it still shows  class="highcharts-axis-title".  Or is it supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

For using custom or local font, in next.js you can add a global css font and use it like this:

I have used Persian font.

**The global css file:**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myFont;
  src: url("../fonts/IRANSansXFaNum-Regular.woff2");
}
    
html,
body {
  font-family: myFont;
}
```

**The component using Highchart:**

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsExporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';

export default function Chart(){
//ssr 
 if (typeof Highcharts === 'object') {
    HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);
  }

const options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      style: {
        fontFamily: 'myFont',
        fontSize: '20px',
      },
    },
}

return (
    <div>
    <HighchartsReact
       highcharts={Highcharts}
       options={options}
       constructorType={'chart'}
      />
    </div>)
}
```